# Most effectively write proofs for multi column journals

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

This is not a question about typesetting. I am interested in learning the best way to decide what to include in multi-column proofs.

I'm writing my first proof for a multi column journal. The main problem i find is that theres not enough space to write algebra, since equations cannot be more than one column wide. I frequently end up listing all the properties required to obtain a result, then state the answer because there is little space for equations. Terms wider than the column width cannot be typeset altogether, for instance. I don't think this type of proof is very convincing, and is looking for alternative way to do it.

In your opinion, what is the most effective way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Publish in a better journal?